# How to replace cell value with specific item if the original value appears in a list? Excel

Tags: excel, list, worksheet-function, cells, cell-formatting

I have a cell containing an abbreviation.
I have a list of abbreviations and their full names and details in a different tab (five columns).

What I need to to check if the abbreviation appears on the list. If it does, I want to replace the abbreviation with the full name from the list, as well as paste the other 3 columns containing the details in the cells right after the full name.
If the value is NOT in the list, I need to format the cell so I can see it, like making its background yellow or red.

Can this be done? If so, how?
Thanx guys, I'm wrecking my brain over this!

```
For Example
```

**Sheet1**:

```
       Column A
1  J Am Soc Echocardiogr
```

**Sheet 2**:

```
         Column A                            Column B                             Column C     Column D     Column E                                     
1  J Am Soc Echocardiogr  Journal of the American Society of Echocardiography       4.254      30/124       1
```

What I want is to get cells in **Sheet 2** columns B to E instead of the original cell on **Sheet 1** (each in a different cell, same row).

Comment: This is precisely what the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is designed to do.

Comment: What code have you tried.  A formula cannot refer to itself, so replacing the value in the same cell will not work with a formula it will need to be in another cell.

Comment: You can do the background colour part though with conditional formatting

Comment: @Scott Craner that's fine, I plan to later extract data using SQL and MVC, so it doesn't really matter which cell it'll be in, I can always change that.

tigeravatar wouldn't that only do a small part of what I need?

Comment: I tried to use vlookup to do this, but I ran into a problem: the value of the cell from which I need to take the information is the result of a function, and so I only get "#N/A" as a result of the vlookup:
=VLOOKUP(E19, Journals!A:E, 1)

The value in E19 is:
= LEFT(MID(MID(D19, FIND(".", D19)+1, LEN(D19)), FIND(".",MID(D19, FIND(".", D19)+1, LEN(D19)))+1, LEN(MID(D19, FIND(".", D19)+1, LEN(D19)))), FIND(".",MID(MID(D19, FIND(".", D19)+1, LEN(D19)), FIND(".",MID(D19, FIND(".", D19)+1, LEN(D19)))+1, LEN(MID(D19, FIND(".", D19)+1, LEN(D19)))))-1)
comes out: " J Clin Hypertens (Greenwich)"

Answer (score 0):

One method may be to use the indirect function - at least for the first part of the question.

If you enter J_Am_Soc_Echocardiogr in A1, then have a lookup list with the full text somewhere else, but name the range "J_Am_Soc_Echocardiogr" by entering the formula `=Indirect(A1)`, it will give the contents of the cell with the named range from A1.

So step one, create and populate your named range:

[image: Named range]

Then Step 2, refer to the named range with an indirect formula:

[image: Indirect reference to named range]